# nextjs minio.client Cant convert stream to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, minio

im trying to create a REST api path to get a full json with this code but i get " [] " or only the first item

i try sending the stream direct to `resolve`

```
export async function GET() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const objectsStream = s3Client.listObjectsV2('node', '', true, '')
        objectsStream.on('data', function (obj) {
            console.log(obj)
            resolve(NextResponse.json((obj)))

        })
        /* Error Hand */
        objectsStream.on('error', function (e) {
            resolve(NextResponse.json(e))
        })


    })
}
```

console log

```
{
  name: '00002.png',
  lastModified: 2023-12-28T15:44:26.762Z,
  etag: 'f1684b805ec19d1cd993a50173acb64b',
  size: 13664646
}
{
  name: '00040.png',
  lastModified: 2023-12-28T15:44:39.300Z,
  etag: '23efca60e3ca26165f1bb12a9e19d223',
  size: 5197315
}
```

got only the first item

```
{
  "name": "00002.png",
  "lastModified": "2023-12-28T15:44:26.762Z",
  "etag": "f1684b805ec19d1cd993a50173acb64b",
  "size": 13664646
}
```

then i try to make it an array

```
export async function GET() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const objectsStream = s3Client.listObjectsV2('node', '', true, '')
        objectsStream.on('data', function (obj) {
            const arr = Object.assign([], obj);
            console.log(arr)
            resolve(NextResponse.json((JSON.stringify(arr))))

        })

        objectsStream.on('error', function (e) {
            resolve(NextResponse.json(e))
        })


    })
}
```

console log

```
[
  name: '00002.png',
  lastModified: 2023-12-28T15:44:26.762Z,
  etag: 'f1684b805ec19d1cd993a50173acb64b',
  size: 13664646
]
[
  name: '00040.png',
  lastModified: 2023-12-28T15:44:39.300Z,
  etag: '23efca60e3ca26165f1bb12a9e19d223',
  size: 5197315
]
```

but i got `[]`  im 100% im doing it wrong but why? what im missing here ???

Comment: I would guess that `.on("data", ...)` triggers when *some* of the data has been downloaded, and another event like on complete or on end (?) triggers when *all* of the data is downloaded.  So currently you are only sending back part of the data.

Comment: ty you put me in the correct path i fix it <3